# take multiple pictures continuously with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to take multiple pictures one after another with `UIImagePickerController`?

I'm aware that there is a method `takePicture` but I'm looking to take 5-10 pictures a second.
For instance, if a user taps a start button on my UI, the app will keep taking images at that rate until they tap stop. I know of plenty of apps that take many pics a second, I just don't know what they're using underneath.

Would that be possible with `UIImagePickerController` or would it require `AVFoundation`? Any pointers or link to tutorials would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the [AVCaptureStillImageOutput class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureStillImageOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It is indeed part of AVFoundation, I have used this method with great success to take pictures every 0.5 seconds:

```
- (void)captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection completionHandler:(void (^)(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error))handler;
```

call this method as much as needed with a timer.

Hope that helps.